# How to make work preparForSegue :sender: XCode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

In my app, I use segment to switch in three view. Every segmment represented with container view and they become hidden or appear according to segment. That is how my the design works, and it works well. You can find the picture below, so you can understand the structure more:

[image]

I'm having trouble with giving an instance (namely, user) created in the view controller to segment's container's view controller. I created user in the user and assign it the values. user instance has the values, I checked it. So, as usual to give with segue, I tried prepareForSegue:sender method to achieve my purpose. In the viewLoad method of the table views(you can find the table views: each of them are attached to its own container in the view controller that has segment. There are 3 containers.) user instances of table views are null. I can't give it, basically. Shouldn't the view controller pass the user value? It might being container view, but still I think it should be :) Anyway, please find below what I have written so far:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        DovizTableViewController *controller = (DovizTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        controller.user = self.user;
}
```

Comment: You don't. remove the Sender all together. There is no sender in prepareForSegue

Comment: remove all sender? What did you mean exaclty?

Comment: `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{ your code }`

Comment: Hmm. I'm now trying it. However can I ask you, doesn't the prepareForSegue method is a built-in method implemented as prepareForSegue:sender ?

Comment: No. It's just preparing to change views and preloads any details that will passed before hand to prevent any loss. Ideally you should also have an if statement in there that checks whether the new view exists by checking for an id and if so pass the details.

Comment: Yeah I know what you meant with if statement, added it right away. You ar right, forgot those. And thanks for the explanation. It's still null, however maybe it is not the problem so I will look code again.

Comment: It will be null because you are setting the data to the navigation controller not the next view. I will try to elaborate on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would remove the sender part of your code.

It should look like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{ 
    //your code 
    //check if the next view exists by checking for the id
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Segue_Name"])
    {
        DovizTableViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
        controller.user = self.user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
            {
                // Get reference to the destination view controller
                 DovizTableViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];

                // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
                controller.user = self.user;
            }
    }
```

Hope it helps.